# Leave out some details on the resource in laravel based on what is passed from request

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel Api resource:

Well basically I have a resource which is tied to a model, but this resource which upon fetching, i also obtain the related model resource e.g.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class ExampleResource extends Resource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "user" => new UserResource($this->user),
            "total" => number_format($this->getTotal(), 2),
            "details" => ExampleDetailsResource::collection($this->details),
        ];
    }
}
```

So with this, my question is:

when am fetching all Examples, I don't want to fetch their details as well,

But when am fetching an example, I need these details.

So is there a way to inform the resource that, I don't need this details when am fetching the details.

The reason why I need to do this is  because, an example can have many details and therefore whenever I fetch all the examples this means I will also get be fetching their details as well which slows down my fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create ExampleDetailResource and ExampleResource, when you don't want more detail call ExampleResouce and vice versa. like this

for less detail in response,

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class ExampleResource extends Resource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "user" => new UserResource($this->user),
            "total" => number_format($this->getTotal(), 2),
        ];
    }
}
```

for more detail in response,

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class ExampleDetailResource extends Resource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "user" => new UserResource($this->user),
            "total" => number_format($this->getTotal(), 2),
            "details" => ExampleDetailsResource::collection($this->details),
        ];
    }
}
```

in your index method inside controller,

```
return response()->json(new ExampleResource($data),200);
```

in your show method inside controller

```
return response()->json(new ExampleDetailResource($data),200);
```